# Setting a session variable in Global.asax causes AJAX errors

Tags: asp.net, javascript, global-asax

I'm getting a very peculiar problem with my asp.net application, it took me an age to track down but I still don't know what is causing this behaviour.

If I set a session variable in the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` event, then my external JavaScript files are ignored, and therfore causing a raft of errors. I have simplified the problem below.

E.g.

I have file called `JScript.js` containing the code:

```
function myAlert() {
 alert("Hi World");
}
```

And in my `Default.aspx` file I reference the js with the code:

```
<script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in the body `onload` event I call the `myAlert()` function:

```
<body onload="myAlert()">
```

And finally in the `Global.asax` file:

```
Private Sub Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   HttpContext.Current.Session("myVar") = "MyValue"
End Sub
```

If you run the `Default.aspx` file you will see the js function isnt called, however, if you comment out the line of code `Global.asax` then the external js is called and the function executed when the page loads.

Why is this?

Comment: Do you have wild card mapping enabled for this application?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PreRequestHandlerExecute event runs twice. Once for the ASPX file and once for the JS file. The problem happens when the PreRequestHandlerExecute event runs when JS file is requested by the ASPX page. Session is NULL (or Nothing) for the JS file which causes an exception. Since an exception occurs for the JS file, the content of this file (your myAlert function) is never loaded into the ASPX page. Therefore, the ASPX page cannot call the myAlert function because the JS file was never loaded.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks very much.

Comment: Is there a way to test which file is causing the PreRequestHandlerExecute to fire? Or would it be better to test if the  Session IsNot Nothing before using it.